# Creating a custom comman with rails rest api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

this is probably a very stupid question but I am very new to rails. I am trying to create a custom command like the one listed bellow, but can't figure out how to call it. I am having no problems with showing an index or sending a create action, I am just having trouble with commands I have created my self. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is the command I am trying to use(It would take the paramaters sent and find the corresponding period through its name):

```
def find
  respond_with Period.find(:name => (params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a member route on your resource, assuming your resource is periods. In your `routes.rb`

```
resources :periods do
  get 'find', :on => :member
end
```

You can find more information in the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions